# send string with ajax with post method in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

this is jquery code:

```
field1="11111",field2="2222",field3="3333"
    $.ajax({
       url:"getdata" ,
       data:{'field1' : field1 , 'field2':field2 , 'field3':field3 },
       processData: false,
       type:'post'
    });
```

this is route in laravel:

```
Route::post('getdata',function(){
   $datadata=Input::post('field1');
   return $datadata ;
});
```

when i use get method that work correctly.but when i want to use post method this error happen in laravel:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::post()
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to get POST data in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You use `Input::get()` for both, GET **and** POST data.

```
Route::post('getdata',function(){
    $datadata = Input::get('field1');
    return $datadata ;
});
```

The `get()` method name doesn't refer to the HTTP verb but rather just means that it is a getter method.

Comment: What do you get with `Input::all()`?

Comment: also that return null

Comment: That can't be. `Input::all()` always returns an array. (It can be empty but not null) Try `var_dump`ing the result.

Comment: that return array(0){}

Comment: when i send one string that work.but when i want to send more than one string that does not work

Comment: How does the request data look like in your browsers network console

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.stringify` when you posting javascript arrys or objects,

change ajax as,

```
 $.ajax({
   url:"getdata" ,
   data: JSON.stringify({ field1 : field1 , field2:field2 , field3:field3 }),
   processData: false,
   type:'post'
});
```

in controller,

```
Route::post('getdata',function(){
   $datadata=Input::json('field1');
   return $datadata ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests):

> You do not need to worry about the HTTP verb (=method) used for the request, as
>   input is accessed in the same way for all verbs.

Meaning there is no such thing like `Input::post()`.
 You can just use `Input::get()` for any method.
This will work:

```
Input::get('field1');
```